# Extract digits between two strings in multiline

Tags: regex

I have a text like this

```
Programme LASER
BlahBlahBlahBlah 2.3.2
Version BlahBlahBlahBlahBlahBlah 1.0
=========

Programme JEDI BlahBlahBlahBlah
Xcc 1.2.0 BlahBlah
BlahBlahBlahBlah
==============
```

FIRST: I need to extract pattern `(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)+` (Only version numbers) between patterns LASER & ======

I succeeded to get full match between LASER and === sequence like this

`(?<=LASER).*?(?=\==)`

I need to return Group 1 = `2.3.2` and Group 2 `1.0`

SECOND : Same Regex must be match for patterns JEDI & ======
Return Group 1 = `1.2.0` and no group 2

Thanks for your help !

Comment: To clarify a little bit more...you do only want to match version numbers of the program "LASER"? Also, will there always be an "Alpha" and "Beta" version number, and no more?

Comment: Maybe https://regex101.com/r/48zq0J/1? `\bLASER\s+\S.*\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)\s+\S.*\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)`

Comment: You can optionally match the version numbers `^Programme \S.*\r?\n.*?(?: (\d+(?:\.\d+)+))?\r?\n.*?(?: (\d+(?:\.\d+)+)|$)` https://regex101.com/r/gq2jbS/1 and for only LASER `^Programme LASER\r?\n.*?(?: (\d+(?:\.\d+)+))?\r?\n.*?(?: (\d+(?:\.\d+)+)|$)` https://regex101.com/r/IkB1WK/1

Comment: @coincoin22 It works right? https://regex101.com/r/VOosaV/1

Comment: No, I need to capture only versions numbers between Programme LASER and === patterns

Comment: @coincoin22 Like this https://regex101.com/r/9Q5Ppm/1

Comment: @coincoin22 Did [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65002505/5424988) I posted work out?

Answer (score 0):

If it's not always `Alpha` and `Beta`

I think you need to split your text into multiple parts and get them versions in another expression:

1. The regex gets your `LASER` part of versions.

**regex:** `\bLASER((?:[^\d=]*[\d.,]+)*)\b`

See [regex-demo1](https://regex101.com/r/gq2jbS/3)

```
Programme LASER
Version Alpha 2.3.2.1
Version Beta 1.0
=========
Programme JEDI
Version Alpha 1.2.0
Version Beta 2.0
==============
```

to

```
Version Alpha 2.3.2.1
Version Beta 1.0
```

2. The regex gets the versions of the `LASER` part.

**regex:** `(?i)\bVersion\s*(\w+)\s*([\d.,]+)\b`

See [regex-demo2](https://regex101.com/r/gq2jbS/2)

- group1: `(\w+)` is version-name.
- group2: `([\d.,]+)` is version-number.

Try the substitution `('$1', '$2')`to get the result like:

```
('Alpha', '2.3.2')
('Beta', '1.0')
```

Comment: How to capture Versions pattern inside ``` (?<=Programme\sLASER).*?(?=\==) ```

Answer (score 0):

You could match the laser part, then match all lines that do not start with Version.
For the lines that start with version, get the optional version number.

As there are 2 Version numbers in the example data, you can use 2 capturing groups.

```
^Programme LASER\b.*(?:\r?\n(?!Version).*)*\r?\nVersion\b[^\d\r\n]*(?: (\d+(?:\.\d+)+))?(?:\r?\n(?!Version).*)*\r?\nVersion\b[^\d\r\n]*(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)+)|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/CkYhhk/1)